# Passing structure which contains string as a data member via socket c++

Tags: c++, string, sockets

I am trying to pass the structure via socket. At receiving end i am not able to retrieve the complete structure passed.

If a structure contains string member variable , how it will be passed via socket ??, how the byte array received at other end can be used to form the structure again.??

Here i am facing the problem with the string member. Because string does not have the size.

Comment: What Socket implementation are you using? "*Because string does not have the size.*" - `std::string` for sure does.

Comment: As for your problem, you mention arrays and strings, are they perhaps pointers? Then think about what you really send... The *pointer*, and not what it might point to.

Comment: You may want to serialize your structure first. [https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization) XML or JSON may be good options.

Comment: Also see [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and [Binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Comment: *If a structure contains string member variable , how it will be passed via socket ??* -- You don't pass that structure.  You pass something else that represents the structure's data.  Then the receiver puts together the struct on their side of the fence with this data.

Comment: Be aware that even sending a most simple `int` in binary format can produce pretty much trouble; sender and receiver side might use different size for `int` and they might disagree on byte order (little or big endian?). If you only use that simple types, but of different size, padding inserted into the struct might vary on both systems (i. e. the systems use different offsets for one and the same member). So just having `MyStruct s = ...; send(mySocket, &s, sizeof(s), 0);` offers far more possibilities for failure even without a string included.